# How to get a ng-model value from another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to access the value of the model `date` from another controller, and make a request passing this value in a json object. But this `ng-model` is in the scope of the controller `DateParseCtrl` and this `controller` is inside another controller called `mainController`. How can I access this value and pass to a json object from `mainController`? Ps: I just want get `date` value from `mainController`.

index.html

```
<body ng-controller='mainController'>
    <datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" selector="form-control"
                ng-controller='DateParserController'>
         <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{ format }}"
                ng-model='date' ng-blur='getSomething()'/> 
    </datepicker>
</body>
```

date-parse-ctrl.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('DateParserCtrl', function($scope, uibDateParser){
    $scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
    $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

mainController

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('mainController',  function($scope, $http){
    var date = $scope.date;
    $scope.getSomething = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: {date: date}
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With events

date-parse-ctrl.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('DateParserCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope, uibDateParser){
    $scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
    $scope.date = new Date();
    var dat=$scope.data;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('sendDate',dat)
});
```

mainController

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('mainController',  function($scope, $http){
    $scope.$on('sendDate',function(event,data){
        $scope.dateFromCtrl=data;
    })
    $scope.getSomething = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: {date: $scope.dateFromCtrl}
        })
    }


});
```

Comment: Also you can fire the event every time the value of date changes, inside the getSomething() function

Comment: I tried include this code `$scope.$on('sendDate',function(event,data){
        $scope.dateFromCtrl=data;
    })`, in the getSomething() function, but it not works :/

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to provide the date as an argument to the `getSomething` function:

```
<body ng-controller='mainController'>
    <datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" selector="form-control"
                ng-controller='DateParserController'>
         <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{ format }}"
                ng-model='date' ̶n̶g̶-̶b̶l̶u̶r̶=̶'̶g̶e̶t̶S̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶(̶)̶'̶
                ng-blur='getSomething(date)' /> 
    </datepicker>
</body>
```

Then  use that argument in the main controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('mainController',  function($scope, $http){
    ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶e̶;̶
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶g̶e̶t̶S̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶{̶
    $scope.getSomething = function(date){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: {date: date}
        })
    }
});
```